# Include JS library in Windows

Tags: javascript, windows

I need to create a simple utility to make my life a little easier. It creates a folder that gets name generated from the next Monday date with DateJS library. I am obviously to use this utility locally in Windows. What are the ways to include this DateJS library to my utility JS file?

Comment: Is this going to run in a webpage or is it a gadget? DateJS, where does this come from? JS is not a normal scripting language in windows except for gadgets and webpages cannot create flders localy.

Comment: @David: That's not really true; the Windows Script Host allows you to execute JavaScript locally with full trust (IE, access to the filesystem via `FileSystemObject`).

Comment: Ok, have neve used WSH with javascript and not seen any examples with it  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using WSH – in other words, putting some script in a `.js` file and running it.  Your options:

- Simply copy the DateJS code from date.js and paste it to the bottom of your script.  Easy, but messy and not maintainable.
- Use the hacky method outlined in the "Importing External Script Code" section of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301529.aspx).  Basically, you read the external code in to a variable and `eval()` it.  I would not recommend this method.
- Save your script in the [`wsf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15x4407c.aspx) format, a simple XML format which allows you to reference external scripts.  This is probably your best route.

myscript.wsf:

```
<job id="myscript">
   <script language="JScript" src="date.js"/>
   <script language="JScript">
      // ...
   </script>
</job>
```

Answer (score -2):

Couple of ways to do this:

1. Go the hardcore route and write a C++ program that embeds [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29)
2. Use something like [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/), which is "basically" HTML and JavaScript in a standalone window
3. Use Windows only [.hta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28VS.85%29.aspx), but you need some J/VBScript stuff then in order to create the folder

If you want more specific answers, you should add more information to your question.